# Number Pattern Recognition. How?

Tags: python-3.x

I got a string of many numbers and was wondering how to go about finding a pattern if there is one without knowing in advance what the pattern might be and what the length of the pattern might be. All it know is that there are only numbers and the maximum range of any given number is 1 - 59.

Example:

12 13 34 45 48 51 56 22 37 30 8 5 47

Although I am starting to think if this was possible it'd be like predicting the future which I don't think it's possible.

Comment: This question is very vague. Could you provide some example inputs and their corresponding outputs you expect?

Comment: -1 What is the question? The example doesn't have any  output either.

Comment: A truly random series of numbers will eventually contain all of these 'patterns' you are hoping to detect, yet you would never be able to use them to predict the next number.  If you know nothing about the string of numbers, you can not be certain that the patterns are conveying intended information from a source. See the Infinite monkey theorem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I guess you would like to do something as they do here:

http://alteredqualia.com/visualization/hn/sequence/

http://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/Sequences-and-series/Sequences-and-series.faq.question.155130.html

That is, looking at the differences between the numbers 1 or more times, and finding patterns. Writing a program to do this for arbitrary sequences is quiet challenging however.